# SQL to populate values in xml list

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

In an SQL Server sproc I need to generate xml using data originating from two different tables. In my example below, the patient number for type EPI comes from one table and the patient number for type MRN comes from another table. To create the xml I am using a UNION to combine the records from two distinct select statements and then using 'FOR XML PATH'. Is there a different way - such as using two select sub-queries without using UNION?

```
<Patients>
  <Patient>
    <Number>1234</Number>
    <NumberType>EPI</NumberType>
  </Patient>
  <Patient>
    <Number>5678</Number>
    <NumberType>MRN</NumberType>
  </Patient>
</Patients>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really want just a list of Numbers and Types wrapped in a 'Patient' element? are the tables related in any way, say by a Patient Id? Are you asking if you can list all numbers and types under one Patient element? Is the above xml sample your true goal or not?

Comment: If you want to fetch data from 2 different table I think union would be good. Check with this link also http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/02/12/sql-server-simple-example-of-creating-xml-file-using-t-sql/

Comment: @Tans - The UNION statement was the best method I found to accomplish what I wanted to do. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @mdisibio - Yes, the xml provided is the required output. The values in the nodes Number and NumberType are extracted from different tables connected via a PatientId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your answer to my question, you are not really joining the tables on PatientId, you are just creating a list of all the data from both tables, and you don't need to group the records by patient.

Yes, `UNION` is the easiest way to accomplish a single list.

However, since you want to output xml, there is an alternate that can be done without `UNION`, per your question:
Assuming you have two tables that might look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE SrcA (PatientId int, NumberA int, TypeA varchar(16));
CREATE TABLE SrcB (PatientId int, NumberB int, TypeB varchar(16));
```

with sample values like this (note how each table has one record not in the other):

```
INSERT INTO SrcA VALUES(100, 1234, 'EPI'), (200, 2222, 'EPI'), (400, 4444, 'EPI');
INSERT INTO SrcB VALUES(100, 5678, 'MRN'), (200, 2121, 'MRN'), (300, 3131, 'MRN');
```

Then the following query:

```
          SELECT
                 (SELECT SA.NumberA AS Number, SA.TypeA AS NumberType WHERE SA.NumberA IS NOT NULL FOR XML PATH('Patient'), TYPE),
                 (SELECT SB.NumberB AS Number, SB.TypeB AS NumberType WHERE SB.NumberB IS NOT NULL FOR XML PATH('Patient'), TYPE)
            FROM SrcA SA
 FULL OUTER JOIN SrcB SB ON SA.PatientId = SB.PatientId
         FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('Patients')
```

will produce:

```
<Patients>
  <Patient>
    <Number>1234</Number>
    <NumberType>EPI</NumberType>
  </Patient>
  <Patient>
    <Number>5678</Number>
    <NumberType>MRN</NumberType>
  </Patient>
  <Patient>
    <Number>2222</Number>
    <NumberType>EPI</NumberType>
  </Patient>
  <Patient>
    <Number>2121</Number>
    <NumberType>MRN</NumberType>
  </Patient>
  <Patient>
    <Number>4444</Number>
    <NumberType>EPI</NumberType>
  </Patient>
  <Patient>
    <Number>3131</Number>
    <NumberType>MRN</NumberType>
  </Patient>
</Patients>
```